# Yotaphone 2 is not visible in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

The Yotaphone 2 is visible as a USB-device, but not in Eclipse's DDMS "Devices". The `development mode` is activated on device.

Any hints would be very helpful!

TIA.

Comment: Does it show up when you list the adb devices?

Comment: Did you install the proper drivers? Did you authorize the computer? Some devices need to be set as MTP device, in their connection options.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Hmm, I found no special usb-drivers for the device. what do you mean by "authorize the computer"?

Comment: Try using a generic driver, then. When you connect the device, if it's recognized by the computer (the correct driver is installed on your PC), it (the device) will ask you to authorize the computer for the USB debugging.

Comment: yeah, did all that... generic driver makes the device be visible as usb stick

Comment: Did you try setting the device as MTP?

Comment: @TʀᴇᴠɪAᴡᴀᴛᴇʀ, no, when I run `adb devices`, the list is empty

Comment: @FrankN.Stein the device was already setup to connect over MTP. switching to PTP brought nothing either

Comment: I have one device which can only be USB debugged in MTP mode.

Comment: My older Xperia could be debugged only in tethering mode. Neither helps with Yotaphone...

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an official USB driver for the YotaPhone 2 on the [YotaPhone website](https://yotaphone.com/gb-en/support/#yotaphone2). So when the phone is plugged in, and USB Debugging has been enabled, the phone appears in Device Manager (Windows) as "Other Devices > Android", with the usual yellow triangle warning showing unknown driver / device.

Because of this, the phone doesn't appear when you run `adb devices` from the command prompt because the computer doesn't know it's an Android device, and therefore won't appear in Eclipse.

However, there is [a driver](https://yotaphone.com/gb-en/support/#yotaphone) on their website for the first generation YotaPhone.

**Continue here at your own risk...**

I modified the `android_usb.inf` file from the first generation YotaPhone and added the Hardware Device ID reported in Device Manager to the end of each list of supported devices in the driver file.

Telling Device Manager to use this new modified file, Device Manager then recognised my YotaPhone 2 and started to install the Android drivers found in the catalog and subfolders.

Device Manager now sees my YotaPhone 2 as: "Android USB Devices > Android Composite ADB Interface (Yota Devices USB ID)"

I haven't tested this with Eclipse (as I don't have it installed), but the phone does now appear when running `adb devices` from the Android SDK Platform Tools folder, and also appears (what I needed it for) in Google Chrome's Inspect Devices for mobile website testing.

I'll [add a link to this driver](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aetltmhhqvf1ekh/YotaPhone%202%20Unofficial%20Driver.zip?dl=0) from my Dropbox account.

**Please note, this is not an official driver for the YotaPhone 2. This is using the same driver for the first generation YotaPhone. I will not be held responsible if anything happens to your YotaPhone 2!!**

Please keep an eye on the YotaPhone website in the hope that an official driver gets released.